# how do i get placeholder when i click on text box

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, placeholder

i have a class Input.js

```
import React from 'react'

export const Form = props => {
const { input, label, type, meta, maxLength, pattern, autoCorrect, 
spellCheck, autoFocus, sublabel, placeholder} = props
const { touched, error } = meta
const { name, value } = input

return (
 <label>
  <input {...input}
    type={type}
    id={name}
    maxLength={maxLength}
    pattern={pattern}
    className={className}
    autoCorrect={autoCorrect}
    spellCheck={spellCheck}
    onBlur={value => input.onBlur(value.target.value.trim())}
    autoFocus={autoFocus}
    placeholder={placeholder}

  />
 </label>
)
}
```

i have added the field

```
       <Field name='dob' label='Birth date'
         component={Form} type='text'
         onChange={this.clearErrors}
         placeholder="MM/DD/YY"
        />
```

i see the text box to be

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lxpU.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMNJ3.png

as you can see i.stack.imgur.com/4lxpU.png ,both the placeholder and the label are at once place which messed it up ..i just wanted to have the label there instead of placeholder and when i click on the text both i want to see as i.stack.imgur.com/eMNJ3.png .

Comment: Where is the `Field` component coming from?

Comment: @CameronDowner https://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/docs/api/Field.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onFocus={(e) => { e.target.placeholder = placeholder }} // this would place text when you click on the input field

```
     import React from 'react'

     export const Form = props => {
     const { input, label, type, meta, maxLength, pattern, autoCorrect, 
     spellCheck, autoFocus, sublabel, placeholder} = props
     const { touched, error } = meta
     const { name, value } = input


    return (
       <label>
       <input {...input}
       type={type}
       id={name}
       maxLength={maxLength}
       pattern={pattern}
       className={className}
       autoCorrect={autoCorrect}
       spellCheck={spellCheck}
       onBlur={value => input.onBlur(value.target.value.trim())}
       autoFocus={autoFocus}
       onFocus={(e) => { e.target.placeholder = placeholder }}
      />
     </label>
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React from 'react'

export const Form = props => {
const { input, label, type, meta, maxLength, pattern, autoCorrect, 
spellCheck, autoFocus, sublabel, placeholder, ref} = props
const { touched, error } = meta
const { name, value } = input

return (
 <label>
  <input {...input}
    type={type}
    id={name}
    maxLength={maxLength}
    pattern={pattern}
    className={className}
    autoCorrect={autoCorrect}
    spellCheck={spellCheck}
    onBlur={value => input.onBlur(value.target.value.trim())}
    autoFocus={autoFocus}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    ref={ref}

  />
 </label>
)
}

class MainComponent extends Component { 
  state={
    value: ''
  }
  onClick = () => {
    console.log(this.refs.dob.placeholder)
  }
  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    })
  }

  onFocus = (event) => {
    this.refs.name.placeholder = ''
  }

  render() {
    return <Field name='dob'
          label='Birth date'
          value={this.state.value}
         component={Form} type='text'
         onChange={this.clearErrors}
         placeholder="MM/DD/YY"
         ref='dob'
         onFocus={this.onFocus}
         onClick={this.onClick}
        />
  }
}
```

Comment: That's how to get the placeholder text. @Tricky spy can you explain well what you want to achieve.

Comment: as you can see  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lxpU.png ,both the placeholder and the label are at once place which messed it up ..i just wanted to have  the label there instead of placeholder and when i click on the text both i want to see as  https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMNJ3.png ...sorry may i was bad at explaining

Comment: I just added some few changes. Add a focus listener to set the value of placeholder to empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You want to hold state that knows when you are focused on the input. An optionally changes the placeholder from the prop to an empty string.

Here is a condensed component with that logic.

```
function Form({ placeholder }) {
  const [focused, setFocused] = React.useState(false);

  function handleOnFocus() {
    setFocused(true);
  }

  function handleOnBlur() {
    setFocused(false);
  }

  return (
    <input
      placeholder={focused ? placeholder : ""}
      onFocus={handleOnFocus}
      onBlur={handleOnBlur}
    />
  );
}
```

[You can see it working on CodePen here.](https://codepen.io/CameronDowner/pen/oOWQwb)